# Can't open new window with background.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a google chrome extension, so what I need is to open links after pressing the button.
I have a problem with creating new window in through background.js. I call the background script using message:

`chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ msg: "startFunc" });`

**background.js:**

```
var func = function(){
    alert("Success!");
    
    chrome.windows.create({ url: "https://google.com" }, function(win) {
        chrome.windows.update(win.id, { focused: false });
    });
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse){
        if(request.msg == "startFunc") func();
    }
);
```

So the success alert does pop up, which is why I think that the problem is with my usage of "chrome.windows.create"

Can anybody please help me with that?

Comment: The code is fine. It opens a window and moves it behind so it's not visible. BTW there's no need for the callback: you can specify `focused: false` right in create().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow these steps.

1. create a button and click event listener on the popup window.
2. send a message from the popup to background script using chrome message-passing API.
3. implement Message listener on background script.
4. inside the listener call the function to create a new window.

**Popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>popup</title>
</head>
<body>
       <button id="test">Click me</button>
<script src="./popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

***Popup.js***

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    console.log("button clicked");
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ msg: "create-window" }, (response) => {
        console.log(response)
    })
})
```

**Background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.msg == "create-window") {
            console.log("message received ")
            createWindow("https://google.com")
            sendResponse({ response: "response from background script" });
            return true;
        }
    });
function createWindow(url) {
    let createData = {
        url: url,
        width: 600,
        height: 400
    }
    chrome.windows.create(createData, (window) => {
        console.log(window)
    })
}
```